# Colouring 9 vertices on a circle.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, circles, coloring

Today I've got a combinatorics problem that I've been trying to solve and I think I have found a good algorithm to get. The problem is the following

> Suppose that there are 9 points in a circle. Tagged from 1 to 9. We want to color theses points with the colours Green, Red and Orange respectively in the following way:

> 1. There must be 3 points coloured with the same color for each of the colours. (No matter their position)
> 2. Any two consecutive points will have a different colour.

So my thoughts are as follows:
Construct a circle with 9 vertices on it $ v_{1}, v_{2}, \cdots, v_{9}$. The vertices will represent any of the points. To get the desire configurations consider the following.

*We will meet any two vertices of the same color with an edge so that a triangle can be constructed of the 3 necessary vertices having the same color for each colour respectively.*
[image]

Now, How many configurations of triangles are there such that the given conditions hold?

In this case we can and first of all, we can choose a vertex in 9 ways. Notice, we cannot color the two adjacent vertices aside that chosen vertex (in the second image if we choose vertex 1 and it is red, we cannot color $v_{2}$ neither $v_{9}$ red.
[image]

Then there are 6 possible choices for the second vertex, once I've chosen this second vertex, I can't choose the two vertices adjacent to it, then I'll have another 4 options for the second vertex, and for the third for the same reasoning I'll have just 2 options. For making the first triangle configuration, there are $ 9( 6\cdot 4 \cdot 2) $.

For the second colored triangle, there are 6 remaining vertices, and by the same process made in the first there are thus $ 6( 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)$  triangles.

The third triangle is fixed due to the selection of the last 2.

Then by the addition principle the number of triangles is $ 6( 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 1) + 9( 6\cdot 4 \cdot 2) = 264 $.

Here I have a question, look that you can choose the color of  that first chosen vertex in 3 ways.

Should I multiply by 3 all the results I've just done or am I be overcounting? Or am I wrong in something above?
Any corrections are welcome, and this is not homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $3$ possible arrangements of the vertices of one colour satisfying the second condition up to rotation and reflection, where the distances between those vertices are respectively $225$, $234$ and $333$. Simple casework then establishes $4$ ways up to rotation that three such arrangements can be packed into the nine points available – all are reflection-symmetric:
[image]

The first and last packings can be oriented in $3$ different ways and the other two in $9$, leading to the final answer of $3!(3+3+9+9)=144$ colourings.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also. Excuse me, but would you tell me please what software did you use to draw the circles?

Comment: @oscarAMVS I've been using Inkscape for years to draw accurate diagrams like this one.

Comment: How time flies... Thanks you, your diagrams are such a wonderful thing!